# How to use dpkg in silent mode

Tags: bash, dpkg

I try to test if some packages are installed in my script before run it. 
To do that by the dpkg command. This is my code :

```
dpkg -s dialog
dialogStatut=$?

if [ "$dialogStatut" -eq 1 ]; then
    //Install package
fi
```

I would like to make dpkg in silent mode (without echo).
I have tried to put >&- 2>&- behind the command but if i do that the value is always 2 (if dialog is installed or not).

I have don't find solution in man dpkg.
What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for 2> /dev/null

```
if ! dpkg -s dialog 2> /dev/null; then
    ...
fi
```

Consider just exiting your script to let `dialog` be installed explicitly rather than making your script responsible for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like

```
dpkg -l dialog &>/dev/null || apt-get install dialog
```

The speciality with OR(`||`) if the first condition evaluates to true(ie an exit status of zero), then the second condition will not be evaluated.